# Django cannot read data from MySQL database after moving it to another VPS

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm writing as I'm stuck with a task that's keeping me busy for a long time now. Basically I have a Django app hosted at Pythonanywhere, and I would like to move it to DigitalOcean VPS.

I've set up the APP on Digital Ocean and it works correctly, static files are loaded and I can see it if I visit the new IP.

What I'm stuck at is when I need to move the data in MySQL from Pythonanywhere to DigitalOcean. Django is not reading the data and my app is empty.

Here's what I've done:

**1.** Did a mysqldump on the DB on Pythonanywhere

**2.** Used the backup to create the same tables and same data in the new DB on DigitalOcean

**3.** Checked that the tables are correctly present in the new VPS's MySQL. Here's the tables on DigitalOcean:

```
| Tables_in_mysitedb      |

| auth_group                 |
| auth_group_permissions     |
| auth_permission            |
| auth_user                  |
| auth_user_groups           |
| auth_user_user_permissions |
| blog_category              |
| blog_post                  |
| blog_post_productos        |
| django_admin_log           |
| django_content_type        |
| django_migrations          |
| django_redirect            |
| django_session             |
| django_site                |
| pages_homepage             |
| productos_product          |
| productos_product_tags     |
| productos_tag              |
| staticpages_about          |
| staticpages_staticpage     |
```

They have exactly the same name as the old ones which where created through Django models.

**4.** Added the database in settings.py of Django on DigitalOcean:

```
  DATABASES = { 'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'OPTIONS': {
                'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
            },
        } 
    }
```

... and this is my.cnf (obviously I stripped credentials).

```
[client]
database = mydb
user = username
password = password
host = localhost
default-character-set = utf8
```

If I do `python manage.py shell` I can retrieve posts correctly.

```
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> posts = Post.objects.all()
>>> for post in posts:
...     print(post.title)
... 
Post title 1
post title 2
etc.
```

It seems to me everything is in place, so why is Django not seeing anything from the database and my app is empty?

If the DB and tables are exactly the same shouldn't this be enough to make it work? I read about the inspectdb command which is supposed to recreate the models based on the tables, but the point is that I already have models for those tables as it's exactly the same data.

I would greatly appreciate any help, I'm stuck and cannot understand how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, adding the answer to help others in case they're having the same issues.

I just had to restart gunicorn:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```